# Set Event WhoId field to only accept Contacts

Tags: contact, event

I think this is not possible but a customer of mine is asking I cannot find anything related to this topic so

**Is it possible to only accept Contacts on WhoId Event field as default?**

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You cannot filter that lookup sadly the best you could do would be a validation rule where ID must start with "003"

```
LEFT( WhoId , 3) = "003"
```

This would be an example this would stop someone from saving the event at least.

Comment: For anyone reading who needs context, the first three digits of an ID indicate the object type - "003" indicates a contact.